# Do Goblin tokens count as Goblins?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a typically mono red Goblins deck.

My question, are tokens considered Goblins too?

For example, I have 10 1/1 Goblin tokens put onto the battlefield by [Krenko, Mob Boss](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKrenko%2c%20Mob%20Boss%5d). Can I use those tokens for [Skirk Fire Marshal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSkirk%20Fire%20Marshal%5d)'s ability?

Comment: the point is, for example i have 10 1/1 Goblin token put onto battlefield by Krenko, mob boss, my question is, i can sacrifice those tokens to play Skirk fire Marshal spell? Skirk fire marshall is: tap 5 untapped Goblins you control, then skirk marshall do 10 dmg to each creature and player

Comment: @user27744 you don't sacrifice goblins to activate Skirk Fire Marshall's ability (you tap them). Unless you mean you also have a Skirk Prospector in play and are just casting the Skirk Fire Marshall?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the tokens created by [Krenko, Mob Boss](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKrenko%2c%20Mob%20Boss%5d) are creatures with the subtype Goblin. That subtype is exactly what the word 'Goblin' on [Skirk Fire Marshal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSkirk%20Fire%20Marshal%5d) is referring to, so you can use them. (They also count for Krenko, Mob Boss' ability if you activate it a second time. Goblin exponentation FTW!)

The relevant [rules](https://media.wizards.com/2019/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020190612.txt) are:

> 110.5c A spell or ability that creates a token sets both its name and its subtype. If the spell or ability doesn’t specify the name of the token, its name is the same as its subtype(s). A “Goblin Scout creature token,” for example, is named “Goblin Scout” and has the creature subtypes Goblin and Scout. Once a token is on the battlefield, changing its name doesn’t change its subtype, and vice versa.
>
> 109.2. If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn’t include the word “card,” “spell,” “source,” or “scheme,” it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.
>
> 110.1. A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, a "Goblin creature token", such as those created by [Krenko](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=438492), has the "Goblin" subtype:

> [110.5c](https://media.wizards.com/2019/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020190612.txt) A spell or ability that creates a token sets both its name and its subtype. If the spell or ability doesn’t specify the name of the
>   token, its name is the same as its subtype(s). A “Goblin Scout
>   creature token,” for example, is named “Goblin Scout” and has the
>   creature subtypes Goblin and Scout. Once a token is on the
>   battlefield, changing its name doesn’t change its subtype, and vice
>   versa.